# read .txt file from s3 bucket not returning all file content

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to read a .txt file content from s3 bucket and return all its lines. I managed to do it this way:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
res = s3_client.Object(bucket_name, key_name)
    

data = res.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()

    
for i in data:
        
   print(i)
```

It printing content but it only prints the 30 last lines and I wanted it to return all of its content.

Comment: The read function on [StreamingBody](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html) returns all data, if you don't specify an amount parameter, so it looks like your code is correct. Have you double-checked this? Have you compared line counts (`len(data)` vs. the file's actual line count ) and are they different?

Comment: Just checked it as you mentioned. len(data) as 55 lines as well as the original file.
I have also checked the Lof Events and there were all the lines printed.

Comment: Then does this mean that, function log window that opens after you test the lambda code has some kind of character limit or something?

Comment: That seems entirely plausible. Go to CloudWatch Logs for this Lambda function. It should show everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudWatch Logs for this Lambda function should be the definitive view of the printed logs.

Your code looks to be correct - the read function on [StreamingBody](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html) returns all data (if you don't specify an amount parameter), so I don't think there's a problem with your code. It *is* receiving the entire file contents.

It looks like the truncated view you are seeing in the Lambda console may simply be a limitation of the console, in order to avoid showing an overwhelming number of lines of output.